# What are recommended dask-kubernetes configuration overrides for long-running tasks?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I am using something along the lines of the example provided in the docs

```py
import dask.bag
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster


cluster = KubeCluster.from_yaml('worker-spec.yml')
cluster.adapt(minimum=0, maximum=24, interval="20000ms")
dag = dask.bag.from_sequence(tasks).map(lambda x: make_task(x).execute())

with distributed.Client(dask_cluster) as client:
    results = dag.compute(scheduler=client)

cluster.close()
```

In my case, the `execute()` function does a lot of IO and takes approximately 5-10 mins to run.  I want to configure the `KubeCluster` and dask scheduler in a way that will maximize the chances of all going well with these long-running tasks.

My question has two parts. First, how do I override a `distributed` configuration setting? I wanted to try something like

```
dask.config.set({'scheduler.work-stealing': False})
```

but I don't know what is the right place to set this.  Specifically, I don't know if this is something that every worker should be aware of or if it is something that I can get away with specifying only at the point where I instantiate the `KubeCluster`.

The second part of my question has to do with recommendations for tasks that will be long-running (more than a few minutes).  I have been experimenting with this using the default settings. Sometimes everything goes well and sometimes the `compute()` call fails with the following exception:

```
  <... omitting caller from the traceback ...>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 436, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2587, in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1885, in gather
    asynchronous=asynchronous,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 767, in sync
    self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 345, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 329, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1741, in _gather
    raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)
distributed.scheduler.KilledWorker: ("('lambda-364defe33868bf6e4864da2933065a12', 3)", <Worker 'tcp://172.18.7.71:39029', name: 9, memory: 0, processing: 4>)
```

I am running a recent commit from the master branch: `dask-kubernetes@git+git://github.com/dask/dask-kubernetes.git@add93d56ba1ac2f7d00576bd3f2d1be0db3e1757`.

**Edit:**

I updated my code snippet to show that I am calling the `adapt()` function with a minimum number of workers set to 0. I started wondering if getting to 0 workers could cause the scheduler to shutdown before it returns the `compute()` result.

Answer (score 0):

> First, how do I override a distributed configuration setting?

You can override settings by either modifying the [configuration YAML files](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#yaml-files) ot by setting [environment variables](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables).

So in your case you can either update your `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml` file.

```yaml
distributed:
  scheduler:
    work-stealing: false
```

Or by setting the environment variable.

```sh
export DASK_DISTRIBUTED__SCHEDULER__WORK_STEALING=False
```

> Sometimes everything goes well and sometimes the compute() call fails with the following exception...

A `KilledWorker` exception happens for a number of reasons. We have included [a documentation page](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/killed.html) about common cases.

Most often I find it is because the task used more memory than was available and it was killed by the OOM killer.